# how to monitor dfs.namenode.handler.count by grafana(opentsdb)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, grafana, opentsdb

like this?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0uZV.png)

my question is if there is also a metric like the one in Red Mashine.
whats the name of it? or if i should define a metric? how to do this?
thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Grafana 2.5's Opentsdb query editor has suggestions enabled by default. So, as you will start typing the name of any metric or even try to put the cursor in the text box, you will see suggestions for the metric name.

If you are using Grafana's older version than 2.5. then you will have to enable certain properties in Opentsdb mentioned [here](http://docs.grafana.org/v2.1/datasources/opentsdb/) in the documentation.